# L2 state in Link Power Management

Tags: linux, usb, power-management, suspend

I have a task where i need to implement L2 Suspend state in Link Power Management. I use a development board where it has DWC3 usb controller interfaced with PHY. Basically our board uses Linux usb DWC3 driver and connected to Host.

My understanding is USB controller generates SUSPEND signal after bus inactivity of 3.125 msec.
Can anyone tell me how can i configure this controller to implement L2 suspend state?

Answer (score 0):

In your current setup, your board is in device/gadget mode and you are connected to host.
Remember that USB device can not drive suspend signalling. It is supposed to be started by Host.

The process of suspend for USB 2.0 device -

> > 1 - USB host has no data to send and currently its sending SOF frames
> >     2 - Host SW suspends the device by setting suspend/U3 in EHCI/XHCI controller
> >     3 - Now the USB device sees idle state in the bus where there is no SOF
> >     4 - After approx 3 ms, the device hardware starts to suspend itself by removing its termination to the ground and connecting the internal pull up register
> >     5 -  Then the device again poll the lines to see whether the host has removed its termination or not.
> >     6 - Since host has removed the termination, the device will go to suspend

Process of suspend for USB 3.0 device -

> > 1 - USB host has no data to send
> >     2 - Host SW suspends the device by setting U3 in XHCI controller
> >     3 - Host starts sending LGO_U3 link commands to initiate the suspend signalling
> >     4 - After device receives LGO_U3 command, it will acknowledge and start suspend

So in conclusion, from USB device you can not start the suspend signalling. You can only set the internal state of the device stack.

EDIT 1 - This process of suspend is for USB 2.0 / High speed devices. If your board is a super speed/ USB 3.0 device connected via SS port to the host, then the process is a little different in link level, but from user point of view there is no difference.
EDIT 2 - I have now updated the answer with suspend process for USB 2.0 and USb 3.0 devices

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shaibal. So you mean to say i don't have to configure the controller? It will generate suspend signal by itself? If yes, any particular register bit it will set after 3msec? OR ISR will get executed?

Comment: Again, your controller is running in device mode. DWC controller can work in host as well as device mode. When running in device mode, it will not drive any signal. The suspend signal is supposed to come from the host where you have connected your board. And yes after suspend, PORTSC will be set to U3 in your controller and you will receive event/interrupt for that. ISR will get executed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the support. One last question, where can i find info about this ISR which gets executed? OR Which part of the code will get execute when interrupt or event comes?

Comment: You need to see if dwc controller device mode driver (udc) is available or not. If not, then you need to implement it. Check kernel/driver/usb/gadget folder. If its available, it should be here. The gadget/device controller driver code will have interrupt handler implemented.